# How to pad a matrix with named rows and columns?

Tags: r, matrix

Suppose you have a matrix (`X`) and a second matrix (`src`) such that rownames of `X` are a subset of the rownames of `src` and the colnames of `X` are a subset of the colnames of `src`.  What is the best way to create a matrix with the rows and columns of `src`, the data of `X`, and with missing data filled in with some default value (such as zero or `NA`)?

Below is my attempt, but I feel there must be a standard way of doing this in R.

```
# Assume row and columns are named
PadColumns <- function(x, src, fill = NA) {
  # pad columns with default values
  result <- matrix(fill, nrow = nrow(x), ncol = ncol(src))
  colnames(result) <- colnames(src)
  rownames(result) <- rownames(x)
  result[,match(colnames(x), colnames(src))] <- x
  result
}

PadRows <- function(x, src, fill = NA) {
  # pad rows with default values
  result <- matrix(fill, nrow = nrow(src), ncol = ncol(x))
  colnames(result) <- colnames(x)
  rownames(result) <- rownames(src)
  result[match(rownames(x), rownames(src)),] <- x
  result
}

PadRowsColumns <- function(x, src, fill = NA) {
  PadColumns(PadRows(x, src, fill = fill), src, fill = fill)
}
```

For example, given

```
X <- matrix(1:6, nrow = 2, dimnames = list(letters[2 * 1:2], LETTERS[2 * 1:3]))
src <- matrix(0, nrow = 4, ncol = 6, dimnames = list(letters[1:4], LETTERS[1:6]))
```

then we should get this:

```
> X
  B D F
b 1 3 5
d 2 4 6
> PadRowsColumns(X, src)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
a NA NA NA NA NA NA
b NA  1 NA  3 NA  5
c NA NA NA NA NA NA
d NA  2 NA  4 NA  6
```

Comment: @JasonAizkalns Good point.  Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subset matrices by row and column names.

```
src <- matrix(1, nrow = 3, ncol = 4, 
              dimnames= list(c("a", "b", "c"), c("A", "B", "C", "D")))
X <- matrix(1:6, nrow = 2, ncol = 3,
            dimnames = list(c("b", "c"), c("A", "C", "D")))
Y <- src
Y[] <- NA
Y[rownames(X), colnames(X)] <- X
```

Comment: Duh! I knew there had to be something simpler than my code. Thanks!